# Add nested object to existing logic in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['xxx xxx','specs','67646546','TEST 123','United States of America']], columns = ['name', 'type', 'aim', 'aimd','context' ])
```

I am trying to add a object 'aimd' under 'data'.
Below is the format

```
{
    "entities": [{
            "name": "xxx xxx",
            "type": "specs",
            "data": {
                "attributes": {
                    "aimd": {
                        "values": [{
                                "value": "xxxxx",
                                "source": "internal",
                                "locale": "en_Us"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "contexts": [{
                        "attributes": {
                            "aim": {
                                "values": [{
                                        "value": "67646546",
                                        "source": "internal",
                                        "locale": "en_Us"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "context": {
                            "country": "United States of America"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit the post to clarify what you're having difficulty with. Please take the [tour], read [ask], and you might want to read [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of inserting an additional array:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame([['xxx xxx','specs','67646546','TEST 123','R12',43,'789S','XXX','SSSS','GGG','TTT','United States of America']], columns = ['name', 'type', 'aim', 'aimd','aim1','aim2','alim1','alim2','alim3','apim','asim','context' ]) 

exclude_list = ['name','type','aimd','context']


data = {'entities':[]}
for key,grp in df.groupby('name'):
    for idx, row in grp.iterrows():
        temp_dict_alpha = {'name':key,'type':row['type'],'data' :{'attributes':{},'contexts':[{'attributes':{},'context':{'country':row['context']}}]}}

        attr_row = row[~row.index.isin(['name','type'])]
        for idx2,row2 in attr_row.iteritems():
            if idx2 not in exclude_list:
                dict_temp = {}
                dict_temp[idx2] = {'values':[]}
                dict_temp[idx2]['values'].append({'value':row2,'source':'internal','locale':'en_Us'})
                temp_dict_alpha['data']['contexts'][0]['attributes'].update(dict_temp)

            if idx2 == 'aimd':
                dict_temp = {}
                dict_temp[idx2] = {'values':[]}
                dict_temp[idx2]['values'].append({'value':row2,'source':'internal','locale':'en_Us'})
                temp_dict_alpha['data']['attributes'].update(dict_temp)

        data['entities'].append(temp_dict_alpha)


print(json.dumps(data, indent = 4))
```

**Output:**

```
print(json.dumps(data, indent = 4))
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "name": "xxx xxx",
            "type": "specs",
            "data": {
                "attributes": {
                    "aimd": {
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "value": "TEST 123",
                                "source": "internal",
                                "locale": "en_Us"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "contexts": [
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "aim": {
                                "values": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "67646546",
                                        "source": "internal",
                                        "locale": "en_Us"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "aim1": {
                                "values": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "R12",
                                        "source": "internal",
                                        "locale": "en_Us"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "aim2": {
                                "values": [
                                    {
                                        "value": 43,
                                        "source": "internal",
                                        "locale": "en_Us"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "alim1": {
                                "values": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "789S",
                                        "source": "internal",
                                        "locale": "en_Us"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "alim2": {
                                "values": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "XXX",
                                        "source": "internal",
                                        "locale": "en_Us"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "alim3": {
                                "values": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "SSSS",
                                        "source": "internal",
                                        "locale": "en_Us"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "apim": {
                                "values": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "GGG",
                                        "source": "internal",
                                        "locale": "en_Us"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "asim": {
                                "values": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "TTT",
                                        "source": "internal",
                                        "locale": "en_Us"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        "context": {
                            "country": "United States of America"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In my scenario my datasource has 50 more columns, under contexts, What I need is under attributes only one column ie., aimd, which is exactly correct from your logic, where as under contexts I will be having 50 more columns, I need to iterate all, Below datasource I have added 5 columns.       df = pd.DataFrame([['xxx xxx','specs','67646546','TEST 123','R12',43,'789S','XXX','SSSS','GGG','TTT','United States of America']], 
columns = ['name', 'type', 'aim', 'aimd','aim1','aim2','alim1','alim2','alim3','apim','asim','context' ])
df

Comment: Updated solution above.